# Regex pattern to match flight number and aircraft registration ID

Tags: python, regex, string

My dataset has Flight number and aircraft reg of the form 'xx-yyy' i.e, two alphanumeric characters 'xx' followed by a hiphen '-' followed by 3 to 5 alphanumeric characters and I want to capture them using regex in python.

Examples:

```
1. pk-bkf
2. id-6236
3. ew-43950
4. 8q-iak
5. q2-274
6. pk-gjr
7. id-12345
```

I tried using this pattern: `^[a-z0-9]{2}[-][a-z0-9]{3, 5}$` but it doesn't seem to match them.

Could someone help me write a pattern with this 'hyphen' inbetween?

Comment: `^(?:[a-z]{2}|\d[a-z]|[a-z]\d)-[a-z0-9]{3,5}$`. The space inside quantifiers is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[a-z0-9]{2}[-][a-z0-9]{3,5}$
```

Seems to be working fine.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/RxbJx7/1